# Configure a Win server 2003 to php

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, php5

We have a Win server 2003 SP2 that we do not use now but it would be great to turn this into a php server.

What we would like is to use the latest php version 5.5.* and all the mod cons, but before i rack my brains and destroy it completely thought best to ask the question here to see if i would have been trying something that in the end will not work etc and end up posting several comments before i find this out etc so if anyone one has pointers/advice etc that would be great.

This will be for a local network for a testing machine. Running Windows Server 2003 SP2 IIS v6

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for some quick testing of small/uncomplicated stuff, just running PHP's built-in server might be enough:

```
php -S [IP to listen to]:[port to listen to] -t [path to your HTML root]
```

For example, you could run the following:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t C:\WWW
```

However, for more serious testing (or even running production code) you should install a real web server and configure it properly to run PHP (you can use IIS, Apache, nginx, etc.).

For an as-simple-as-possible solution, have a look at [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/), which brings you a complete and ready-to-run environment with Apache, PHP, mySQL, and more.

Comment: thanks for the feedback the server currently run classic asp files but we have moved this over to Win 8 machine.  So i will be looking to reformat the server with the 2003 disc, so we have a clean install etc.  Some of us used WAMP for our local machines, just wonder on the network connection to that WAMP install. its using IIS6 so hopefully i might be able to manipulate the IIS and set it to PHP and FastCGI etc

Comment: With IIS you might be able to use Microsoft's installer to Setup everything: http://php.iis.net/

Comment: tahsnk @mario woudl i also be able use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer ? Will feedback

Comment: Of course, I think that page (as well as the redirect) are just entry points for the WPI anyway.